# Mysql select with if else and order by statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select

Without any training (and deaf) I developed a town portal system but I gave up on a specific select statement.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `test` ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`townid`,'townA'), date DESC LIMIT 3 ;

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `townid` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2017-08-30'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `townid`, `data`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 'townB', 'Data for Town B', '2017-08-29'),
(2, 'townA', 'Data for Town A', '2017-08-28'),
(3, 'townA', 'Data for Town A', '2017-08-27'),
(4, 'townA', 'Data for Town A', '2017-08-26'),
(5, 'townC', 'Data for Town C', '2017-08-25'),
(6, 'townB', 'Data for Town B', '2017-08-24');

ALTER TABLE `test`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `test`
  MODIFY `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;COMMIT;
```

The goal is that

- townA select ID 2, 3 and 4
- townB select ID 1, 6 and 2
- townC select ID 5, 1 and 2

In other words the town select his OWN articles first in date order with limit 3, ELSE select the limit 3 or remaining of the limit 3 in date order from any other town.

Neither select WHERE `townid` = 'townB' or WHERE `townid` IN ('townB') can deal with the 3 limit problem where I need THREE results even if there is only 1 of 2 entries for Town B

Comment: Without formal training even a graduate said not many graduates can achieve what I did, but without formal training I only know what I learnt myself and there are most likely a lot of "very easy" things that I don't know. (I never gave up and search and searh and try until I find a solution but this one....)

Comment: While I can't answer for the obstacles that any form of disability might provide, like myself, I suspect that only a minority of individuals on here have had any kind of formal training.

Comment: Nobody to ask in real live - that's my obstacle and while it's easy online I almost never do that as I believe in doing and learning myself. (Grrr some of the code I wrote is perhaps 20 x more difficult than this one but ....)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the comments; People are not saying that your query is easy(or hard) to do, they just want you to provide a few rows of your table, since that makes it way easier to give a meaningfull answer. MCVE stands for MinimalCompleteVerifiableExample.

Comment: Thank you I see so and altered the question. (Almost all the other similar statements I found don't deal with the LIMIT 3 which it seems create a issue of it's own)

Comment: Just add DESC after both order by's  `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(townid,'townA') desc, date desc`  Note https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ provides an easy to use tool for formatting sample data.

Comment: Thank you and bookmarked the link. It works perfect thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost perfect in your sample provided and your query.  The only thing you need to change is the order by find-in-set clause to DESCENDING.

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(townid,'townA') DESC, date DESC
```

The find_in_set() will return a 1 or 0 based on the thing being found (1) or not (0).  So you are ordering by those NOT found first, THEN found.  You want the reverse.  So, even if you have 99 items, and evenly split over each town A, B and C over a span of several days, having the "DESC"ending order on the FIND_IN_SET will say give me all of 'townA' records first, then anyone else after that.  THEN, within each set of FOUND (or NOT) records, sort them in descending date order.

Your query is actually just the one "DESC" clause away.

Comment: two DESC clauses away. http://rextester.com/RBXBQL81555  and spot on for the 1,0 analysis in find in set.

Comment: Wow thank you a lot. I many times sat for many hours and even days to get something like I want it but this one got the better of me hehe (I actually build a system that don't exist anywhere so far as I am aware of but after years not earned $1 with that, yet hehehe)

Comment: Damnit. I did a search and replace on the whole system and it changed everything except the "development" site so when I checked why I found that it actually included the DESC but I discarded the DESC as "not important" for the live town portals.

Comment: @FrankCoetzee, glad it worked, but make sure to mark answers as solution so others know what worked in case they have similar questions.

Comment: I don't often post so still trying to figure out how hehehe

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM test 
 ORDER 
    BY townid = 'townc' DESC -- or 'towna' or 'townb'
     , date DESC
 LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.